# How to bind output event from custom Angular 2 component to reactive form in parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am creating a reactive form in Angular 2 which contains a time picker subcomponent. My time picker component stores the time in a Javascript date object, and whenever the time changes, it fires an event with the date as a parameter which is caught by the parent component.

I know that it is possible to call a function which can set the new value in the form group. However, this seems cumbersome especially as the form grows.

My question is, is there a way I can bind the date object from the time picker component to a form control in my parent component, without explicitly catching an event, or does Angular provide another method?

Here is the child component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'time-picker',
  templateUrl: './time-picker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./time-picker.component.css']
})
export class TimePickerComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() onTimePicked = new EventEmitter<Date>();

  hours = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12'.split(' ').map((x: string) => parseInt(x, 10));
  minutes = '00 15 30 45'.split(' ').map((x: string) => parseInt(x, 10));

  hour: number;
  minute: number;
  meridian: string;
  meridian_offset: number;

  constructor() {

    this.hour = 10;
    this.minute = 0;
    this.meridian = 'AM';
    this.meridian_offset = 0;

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  changeHour(hour: string) {
    this.hour = parseInt(hour, 10);
    this.emitChange();
  }

  changeMinute(minute: string) {
    this.minute = parseInt(minute, 10);
    this.emitChange();
  }

  changeMeridian() {
    if (this.meridian === 'AM') {
      this.meridian = 'PM';
      this.meridian_offset = 12;
    } else {
      this.meridian = 'AM';
      this.meridian_offset = 0;
    }

    this.emitChange();
  }

  emitChange() {
    const newDate = new Date();

    // % by 12 otherwise this is incorrect for noon and midnight
    newDate.setHours(((this.hour % 12) + this.meridian_offset) % 24);
    newDate.setMinutes(this.minute);

    this.onTimePicked.emit(newDate);
  }

}
```

Here is a simplified version of the parent component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-visit-request',
  template: `
            <form [formGroup]="form" novalidate (ngSubmit)="submit()">

                <!-- Start Date Time -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div formGroupName="start">

                      <label>Start Date<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                      <date-picker [startDate]="startDate">
                      </date-picker>

                      <label>Start Time<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                      <!-- This is the way I currently do it -->
                      <time-picker (onTimePicked)="call function to set value in form"></time-picker>

                      <label>End Time<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                      <!-- This is the way I want to do it -->
                      <!-- <time-picker formControlName="endTime"></time-picker> -->

                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Submit Button -->
                <div class="text-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                        Submit
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>`
})
export class NewVisitRequestComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  startDate = new Date();

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      start: this.fb.group({
        date: [this.startDate, Validators.required],
        time: [{ hour: 8, minute: 0 }, Validators.required]
      })
    });
  }


  submit() {
    console.log(this.form.controls);
  }

}
```

Comment: Well, if the event is caught by the parent, then pass the date in that event as parameter. I don't know what help you are expecting to get with no code provided, not what you have tried or what is not working. So this is probably the best answer you'll get based on this information ;)

Comment: @AJT_82 I updated my question with some more details. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What you want to do seems totally possible, cannot help more since we are not seeing any code... ;)

Comment: @AJT_82 updated with code

Comment: I guess you need to implement `ControlValueAccessor`

Comment: @yurzui i think thats what i was getting at. Thanks!